# Spring 3.x.x MVC jsp combobox trouble

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I've been going in circles for a couple of days without any progress at trying to get a simple combobox (made by a form:select) working with Spring-MVC 3.x.x and jsp. There are several examples that are implemented by extending the now deprecated "SimpleFormController", however I haven't found any succinct sample using Spring 3.0.x annotations. Also, I've already looked into the Spring's reference  [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/) , but I couldn't get a snippet of both a controller and a view (jsp) that can lead me to make a combobox component run.
       
        So far, what I've unsuccessfully tried is something like this: (any comment would be really appreciated)

**Controller Class (e.g. MyController.java)**

```
@Controller
public class MyController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showHomePage(ModelMap model) {

        Map<String,String> country = new LinkedHashMap<String,String>();
        country.put("US", "United Stated");
        country.put("CHINA", "China");
        country.put("SG", "Singapore");
        country.put("MY", "Malaysia");
        model.put("countryList", country);
        return "home";
    }
}
```

**home.jsp**

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%><br>
<html>
<body>
<form:form method="POST" commandName="country">
    <form:select path="country">
        <form:options items="${countryList}" />
    </form:select>
</form:form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I have used this in the past is to create a bean named OptionValue with two properties value and description.  Add the list of OptionValue's to the model.  The form option tag will need to know what properties to look for the value and description.  I have added a sample below.

```
@Controller
public class MyController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showHomePage(ModelMap model) {

        List<OptionValue> country = new ArrayList<OptionValue>();
        country.add(new OptionValue("US", "United Stated"));
        country.add(new OptionValue("CHINA", "China"));
        country.add(new OptionValue("SG", "Singapore"));
        country.add(new OptionValue("MY", "Malaysia"));
        model.put("countryList", country);
        return "home";
    }
}
```

In your jsp.

```
<form:options items="${countryList}" itemValue="value" itemLabel="description"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Manuel clarification, I finally came up with a functional and satisfactory **solution**. Here I copy the to main components that makes it work:

**CountryBean Class (e.g. CountryBean.java)**

```
@Component
public class CountryBean {
    private String value;
    private String description;

public CountryBean(){
}
public CountryBean(String value, String description){
    this.value=value;
    this.description=description;
}

public String getValue() {
    return value;
}
public void setValue(String value) {
    this.value = value;
}
public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}
public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}
}
```

**CountryFormBean Class (e.g. CountryFormBean.java)**

```
public class CountryFormBean {

private CountryBean countryBean;

public setCountryBean (CountryBean countryBean){
    this.countryBean=countryBean;
}

public CountryBean getCountryBean(){
    return countryBean
}
```

**Controller Class (e.g. MyController.java)**

```
@Controller
public class AttendanceController {
private List<CountryBean> countryBeanList;
public List<CountryBean> getCountryBeanList() {
    return countryBeanList;
}
@Autowired
public void setCountryBeanList(List<CountryBean>  countryBeanList) {
    this.countryBeanList = countryBeanList;
}
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showHomePage(@ModelAttribute("countryFormBean") CountryFormBean countryFormBean, BindingResult result, ModelMap model) {


    countryBeanList.add(new CountryBean("US", "United Stated"));
    countryBeanList.add(new CountryBean("CHINA", "China"));
    countryBeanList.add(new CountryBean("SG", "Singapore"));
    countryBeanList.add(new CountryBean("MY", "Malaysia"));

    model.addAttribute("countryBeanList", countryBeanList);
    return "home";
}
}
```

**home.jsp**

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<html>
<body>
<form:form method="POST" commandName="countryFormBean">
 <form:select path="countryBean"  items="${countryBeanList}" itemValue="value" itemLabel="description"/>
</form:form>
</body>
</html>
```